# Space ship deceleration from speed of light

Tags: space-travel, spaceships

A space ship travels (almost) at the speed of light. When it nearly reaches its destination it starts decreasing the speed. What would be the most appropriate deceleration for human body in such conditions?

Astronauts endure around 3G on lift-off, which is about 29.4 $m/s^{2}$, but only for a short time. To decelerate from speed of light to zero then it takes nearly 4 months. Is there any condition that astronauts could be put in, so they can bear the pressure for such a long time, like cryogenic freeze or something else?

Comment: @a4android Please don't answer question in comments. Make an answer to stun us all.

Comment: 4 months isn't all that long if we're talking interstellar or is this interplanetary?  Do these human bodies need to be natural or could they be cyborgs with nanobots instead of cells?  Or maybe their cells have reinforced membranes?

Comment: Javor, "To decelerate from speed of light to zero then it takes nearly 4 months." - sorry, but I think that you missed the point of relativity. It would take an *infinite* amount  of time to do as you say. Could you please specify the physics of your universe?

Comment: @DonQualm The OP probably meant approximately the speed of light. This we can agree on will only take a finite period of time. His four months is only a Newtonian approximation, but it would be closer to shiptime than time in the rest frame.

Comment: @a4android Yes they did mean approximately - *that's the problem*, if the OP can't precisely define the question, then how precisely can the question be answered? That being said, maybe a synthesis is what's needed between the facts and the question. But wouldn't that mean we're writing the story for the OP? What's the worldbuilding problem here?

Comment: The premise of your question is somewhat incorrect, you seem to be using the Newtonian formula t = v/a to figure out the time t needed to decelerate from velocity v to 0 with acceleration a, but that formula becomes increasingly inaccurate the closer your starting v is to light speed. The correct relativistic formulas for a ship undergoing constant acceleration can be found on [this page](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/Rocket/rocket.html), and the equation giving v as a function of T (time onboard the ship) can be rearranged as T = (c/a) * atanh(v/c)

Comment: It simplifies things a bit if you use units like light-years for distance and years for time, in which case c = 1, and an acceleration of 9.8 m/s^2 becomes an acceleration of 1.03 ly/y^2, as mentioned on the relativistic rocket page. Then you could rewrite the expression as (1/(1.03 * g)) * atanh(v) where g is the acceleration in multiples of the acceleration felt at the surface of the Earth. You can plug that equation into the calculator [here](https://keisan.casio.com/has10/Free.cgi) & pick values for g and v to get the onboard time, for ex. with g=3 and v=0.8 you get a time of 0.356 years.

Comment: Also, in your [other question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/150187/intragalactic-velocity-past-the-central-black-hole) you mentioned wanting a time dilation factor of 2000/66 million, and I mentioned that this could be done with a velocity of 0.999999999540863177124 times light speed. If we plug that into the equation I gave in my previous comment and use the calculator I linked, it tells us the onboard time to decelerate from that speed to 0 (or accelerate from 0 to that speed) would be 10.774 years at acceleration g=1, 5.387 years at g=2, and 3.591 years at g=3.

Comment: @DonQualm While I would welcome more precisely written questions here. Human fallibility on the part of OPs is all too often. I prefer more lattitude instead of rigidity. No it wouldn't mean writing the story for the OP. The worldbuilding problem is about determining a suitable acceleration & whether counter-acceleration technologies are needed. Nothing wrong with a little hand-holding to help OPs learn what they need to learn. Hypnosifl is a prime example. More power to his arm.

Answer (score 16):

If the spaceship was decelerating at one g, meaning a comfortable 9.8 $m/s^{2}$, then deceleration will take roughly one year shiptime. No need for special counter-acceleration measures. Plus, it provides convenient environment for astronauts to work and play in, while decelerating. Also, time to survey their destination prior to their arrival.

However, the spaceship will actually need to decelerate for the same length it took to accelerate to near-lightspeed. For preference, and the comfort of crew and passengers and any stowaways lurking the bowels of the starship, this should be one g (for reasons given above in one paragraph).

Accelerations and decelerations of one g are the most appropriate for spacecraft approaching lightspeed (assuming we can ignore the energetic requirements for such interstellar space travel, because they're astronomically mind-boggling).

Comment: +1 for mentioning the energy requirements - they make such ultra relativistic travel very unrealistic.

Comment: @StephenG My sentiments exactly. Even modestly relativistic space travel is incredibly energy greedy. It's fine for science fiction stories, but for realistic spaceflight not so. Relativistic travel is a physical possibility, but a practical impossibility

Comment: If the target planet has a known gravity, the best deceleration may be to match that - or, if the gravity is higher than the Earth's, start with 1 g deceleration and slowly increase to the target planet's gravity..

Comment: @a4android - There are possibilities for getting things close to light speed without having to carry the fuel onboard, so you don't have to deal with the [relativistic tsiolkovsky equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation#Special_relativity) implying a huge ratio of fuel mass to payload mass. One idea is to aim an enormous laser array in the solar system at a ship with a solar sail, another is to magnetically accelerate a stream of small pellets to near light speed with something like a magnetic coilgun, which could push against a magnetic sail (magsail) on the ship.

Comment: (a magsail can also potentially be used for decelerating using particles in the interstellar medium without needing to have fuel onboard, see [here](https://www.centauri-dreams.org/2012/03/16/starships-the-problem-of-arrival/) and [here](https://www.centauri-dreams.org/2012/03/19/braking-against-a-stellar-wind/))

Comment: @kleer001 - You didn't include any acceleration factor--if you're not calculating the time needed to decelerate, what were you calculating? I think a4android's comment about it taking "roughly one year" was based on the Newtonian formula for velocity change as a function of time assuming constant acceleration delta-v=at which implies the time for a velocity change is t = delta-v / a, so if you have delta-v as 299792458 m/s (light speed) and a as 9.8 m/s^2 this gives a time of 30591067 s, about a year. But as I pointed out in the comments to the OP, this isn't an accurate formula in relativity.

Comment: @Hypnosifl  dunno, I'll delete it

Comment: @Hypnosifl Without trying sound grumpy or arrogant, but as a proverbial space buff I am familiar with the concepts. Even so, they still do require astronomical amounts of energy to get up to relativistic velocities. Low-speed, non-relativistic interstellar travel is more plausible IMHO. Thanks for the links. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Hypnosifl My comment about "roughly one year" was both a loose allusion to the Newtonian approximation, and more about the elapsed proper time onboard the decelerating spacecraft (which is closer to the roughly one year than the time passing in the relative rest frame). I really should crunch the numbers to find out accurately the times in the different reference frames instead of guesstimating approximations..

Answer (score 4):

**Carbonite.**

[image: han solo in the carbonite]

https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWars/comments/1tcact/the_original_han_solo_in_carbonite_prop_on/

"Freeze" your spacefarers in carbonite.  How does carbonite work, you may ask?

> Carbonite was a liquid substance that was made from carbon gas and
>   could change into a solid through rapid freezing. Goods could be
>   encased in carbonite for preservation, through a process known as
>   carbon-freezing,[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJJkJ.jpg)
>   Carbonite blocks could also be used to place people in hibernation.[3]
>   Before the invention of the hyperdrive, some early spacers would use
>   carbonite to endure long voyages. That technique, however, had brutal
>   side effects, collectively referred to as hibernation sickness.
>   https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Carbonite

(waves hands) There you go!  They even used it for what you want to use it for.

Remember to make a funny face as the carbonite flows around you.

Do not freeze people in carbonite if you exist in a hard science world.

Do not confuse carbonite with the explosive of the same name.